# grep recursive with wild card not working

Tags: linux, grep

```
$ grep -r 9900 *.mk
grep: *.mk: No such file or directory
$ grep -R 9900 *.mk
grep: *.mk: No such file or directory

$ grep -V
GNU grep 2.5.4
```

am I using a wrong grep? or what is the syntax? Thanks!

Comment: `find . -type f -name \*.mk -exec grep 9900 {} +`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the include flag:

```
grep -r --include="*.mk" 9900 .
```

grep manual page says:

> --include : If specified, only files matching the given filename pattern are searched.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution of `*.mk` happens in the shell, not in grep, *before* grep gets to apply recursion.  Since the current directory doesn't contain any files matching the pattern, the patten literal is passed to grep. Grep does not know how to expand the pattern -- it just tries to find files named literally `*.mk` which, of course, it can't.

Use

```
find . -type f -name \*.mk -exec grep 9900 {} +
```

instead